# Can't get the same order of my dataframe arranged by Date

Tags: sql, r, database, dataframe

I have a date frame arranged by Date:

```
    data1<-merged.tables[Open==1,list(min(as.numeric(Sales)),mean((as.numeric(Sales))),max(as.numeric(Sales))),by=c('StoreType','Date')]
> data1[order(as.Date(data1$Date)),]
      StoreType       Date   V1        V2    V3
   1:         b 2013-01-01 2401  5895.500 17267
   2:         a 2013-01-01 2907  2907.000  2907
   3:         c 2013-01-02 1198  6372.714 20493
   4:         a 2013-01-02 1402  6512.269 25357
   5:         d 2013-01-02 1816  5694.315 20355
  ---                                          
3545:         b 2015-07-30 5625 11128.647 22253
3546:         c 2015-07-31 3377  9109.318 18690
3547:         a 2015-07-31 2726  8967.260 27508
3548:         d 2015-07-31 4239  9096.796 23996
3549:         b 2015-07-31 6975 12677.765 25774
```

Then I need to get my dataframe where the **Date** column is transformed  to **year-month** type. So I used this:

```
> data1$Date<-format(as.Date(data1$Date),"%Y-%m")
> head(data1$Date)
[1] "2015-07" "2013-01" "2014-01" "2014-12" "2013-11" "2015-06"
```

But this is not arranged to the Ascending order. In fact the issue below should be:

```
  2013-01 2013-01 2013-01 2013-01 2013-01 2013-01
```

The same my data frame is not arranged as I need.

How can I arrange my data frame without having the risk to mix values and having no correspondance between values of `v1,v2,v3` and their real dates?

thank you in advance!

Comment: `data1 <- data1[order(as.Date(data1$Date)),]`
you need to assign back to data1, the re-ordered data frame

Comment: @JonnyPhelps, thank you! It works